# Change the format of some strings

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have strings in this format:

```
Puntata del 16 Agosto 2018
Puntata del 17 Gennaio 2018
Puntata del 7 Novembre 2017
Puntata del 2 Gennaio 2013
```

I would like to get:

```
20180816
20180117
20171107
20130102
```

How can I do that?

That is the year, the month (in two digits) and the day (in two digits).

For the year it's easy: just take the last four characters of the string, but for the day and the month?

This is the code I am creating:

```
var newName = function(oldName) {
    var oldNameWithoutPuntata = oldName.substring(12);
    console.log('oldNameWithoutPuntata:', oldNameWithoutPuntata);

    var year = oldNameWithoutPuntata.substr(oldNameWithoutPuntata.length - 4);
    console.log('year:', year);

    // ...
    return year + month + day;
}

var test1 = 'Puntata del 16 Agosto 2018';
var test2 = 'Puntata del 17 Gennaio 2018';
var test3 = 'Puntata del 7 Novembre 2017';
var test4 = 'Puntata del 2 Gennaio 2013';
console.log(test1, '-->', newName(test1));
console.log(test2, '-->', newName(test2));
console.log(test3, '-->', newName(test3));
console.log(test4, '-->', newName(test4));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option of finding month value from month names array

1. Use Months Array to find the month value and format it to add '0' ,if it is less than 10
2. Using split(' ') method with space, date can splitted into date, month, year
3. Format month to add '0' ,if it is less than 10

codepen for reference - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/QVzqPZ?editors=1011

```js
var newName = function(oldName) {
  var oldNameWithoutPuntata = oldName.substring(12);
  
  var months = ['Gennaio','Febbraio','Marzo', 'Aprile','Maggio','Giugno', 'Luglio', 'Agosto','Settembre', 'Ottobre', 'Novembre','Dicembre']
  
  var dateArr = oldNameWithoutPuntata.split(' ')
  
  var month = months.indexOf(dateArr[1]) + 1 
  month = month< 10 ? ('0' + month) : month
  var year = dateArr[2];
  var date = dateArr[0]
  date = date< 10 ? ('0' + date) : date
 
  return year + month + date;
}

var test1 = 'Puntata del 16 Agosto 2018';
var test2 = 'Puntata del 17 Gennaio 2018';
var test3 = 'Puntata del 7 Novembre 2017';
var test4 = 'Puntata del 2 Gennaio 2013';
console.log(test1, '-->', newName(test1));
console.log(test2, '-->', newName(test2));
console.log(test3, '-->', newName(test3));
console.log(test4, '-->', newName(test4));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to remove some of the substring slicing if you use the `RegExp` function `exec` which can return match groups from a query although the first element will be the 'whole match'.

Once you have an array of the date pieces, reducing it back to a string in reverse order is achieved via the `reduceRight` array function.

Please note that padStart is a String function so you have to convert the numbers to strings first. This is achieved by concatenating them with an empty string i.e. `('' + <number>).padStart(...)` and I make use of brackets to ensure the correct execution order of the statement

```js
let getMonthAsNumber = month => ['Gennaio', 'Febbraio', 'Marzo', 'Aprile', 'Maggio', 'Giugno', 'Luglio', 'Agosto', 'Settembre', 'Ottobre', 'Novembre', 'Dicembre'].indexOf(month)+1

var newName = oldName => /^Puntata del ([0-9]+)\s([^0-9\s]+)\s([0-9]+)$/gi.exec(oldName)
  // remove the first element of the match array - this is the whole match
  .slice(1)
  // use reduceRight to work along the rest of the match groups 'backwards'
  // apend the strings together and convert/pad as required
  .reduceRight((prev, cur) => prev + (''+(isNaN(cur)? // is 'cur' a string?
  getMonthAsNumber(cur) // yes - convert month to number
  : 
  cur // no - return number
  ))
  .padStart(2, '0'), '')

var test1 = 'Puntata del 16 Agosto 2018';
var test2 = 'Puntata del 17 Gennaio 2018';
var test3 = 'Puntata del 7 Novembre 2017';
var test4 = 'Puntata del 2 Gennaio 2013';
console.log(test1, '-->', newName(test1));
console.log(test2, '-->', newName(test2));
console.log(test3, '-->', newName(test3));
console.log(test4, '-->', newName(test4));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/padStart) to add 0 more easily.

See https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bxOvmy?editors=1011

```js
var newName = function(oldName) {
    var parseDate = oldName.split(' ');
    var monthsList = ['Gennaio','Febbraio','Marzo', 'Aprile','Maggio','Giugno', 'Luglio', 'Agosto','Settembre', 'Ottobre', 'Novembre','Dicembre'];

    var month = monthsList.indexOf(parseDate[3]) + 1;
    month = month.toString().padStart(2, "0");
    var year = parseDate[4];
    var date = parseDate[2].padStart(2, "0");
 
    return year + month + date;
}

var test1 = 'Puntata del 16 Agosto 2018';
var test2 = 'Puntata del 17 Gennaio 2018';
var test3 = 'Puntata del 7 Novembre 2017';
var test4 = 'Puntata del 2 Gennaio 2013';
console.log(test1, '-->', newName(test1));
console.log(test2, '-->', newName(test2));
console.log(test3, '-->', newName(test3));
console.log(test4, '-->', newName(test4));
```